# Julia Gtk: How to get a list of properties for a widget?

Tags: julia, gtk

How do I go about getting a list of all properties for a widget in Julia Gtk?

Comment: When you do `display(widget)`, it lists all its properties as part of its output. There doesn't seem to be a way to programmatically get that as a `Dict` or anything like that, as far as I can tell - the `show` call underneath `display` directly calls the C library to get the list of properties, and that doesn't seem to be available as a separate function. Maybe someone who knows the library has a better answer, if not, I'll add this as an answer in a day.

Comment: Thankyou. Not like python Gtk which has method props()

Comment: Could you mention your use case for getting the list of properties, as in how you plan to use the list? I'm considering opening an issue to request such a  function, and it would be useful to give an example when that would be needed.

Comment: Well, I'm still getting the hang of Gtk programming and have only been using Julia for about 5 months now having come from C#.
I would like a way of examining widgets so I can get at their property names in order to understand and adapt.
display, print, show can all be used but the print-out in the REPL takes some peering into but it gets me there :-)

Comment:  Sure, readability is itself a valid reason for this. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking for the properties that can be called with the `get_gtk_property(aGtkEntryLeafObject, :someProperty, type)` function and thus use the value of `someProperty`. I looked for possible hints everywhere. This is, in fact, very disappointing to see in how terribly sorry state the GTK documentations are still in. However, if so is the case, this might help:

When you run `display(aGtkEntryLeafObject)` you will get all the properties that can be summoned.

For example, I have a text entry box with which I take an input value. The `ID` of the entry box is `iEntry`. I wish to have the input value that has been put in the box.

```
display(glade["iEntry"])
```

Here the `glade["iEntry"]` is the `GtkEntryLeaf` object.

The output of the command is:

[image: output of display(aGtkEntryLeaf)]

Note that the `text` property is there, marked by yellow border in the picture.
So I can summon the property using:

```
get_gtk_property(glade["iEntry"], :text, String);
```

output: `"3.37e-3"`

From the looks of it, I had to guess that the `text` property to be of `String` type. If mentioned otherwise it would have thrown an error.
Now I have to parse this `String` type output for its use as a `Float` type just afterwards.

The things are also very similar if you have other type of controls, i.e., combo-box.

I have a combo-box for which the `GladeEntryLeaf` object is `glade["conditionEntry"]`.
Here for the combo-box `display(glade["conditionEntry"])` has the output:

[image: output of display(aGtkComboboxEntryLeaf)]

So from this output I can get the `text`,`height-request`, `visible` properties, among many other.

```
get_gtk_property(glade["conditionEntry"], :text, String)
```

output: `"HWL"`

```
get_gtk_property(glade["conditionEntry"], :visible, Bool)
```

output: `true`

```
get_gtk_property(glade["conditionEntry"], "height-request", Int)
```

output: `-1`

Note that some properties do not have any value and are `Null`.